# pycharm exercise "Character Escaping": task completed but wrong syntax

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm following the built-in tutorial in PyCharm Edu Edition and I'm stuck on Strings - Character Escaping.
In the exercise I'm asked to print the following:
The name of this ice-cream is "Sweeet'n'Tasty"
by using character escaping, and here's my code:

```
print("The name of this ice-cream is \"Sweeet\'n\'Tasty\"")
```

and it still gives me "Sorry the wrong string is printed". Honestly I don't think I printed a wrong string. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape " because you use it in your print but your ' does not need to be protected.

Printing "\'n" and "'n" will output the same line but the escape, even if not visible, will generate something that is read by your exercise controller.

Try removing the \ before the '

```
print("The name of this ice-cream is \"Sweeet'n'Tasty\"")
```

Another solution for string containing " or ' is to use triple " like this:

```
print("""The name of this ice-cream is "Sweeet'n'Tasty\"""")
```

In this very case, the fact that the sentence is terminated by a " force to protect it again, but the " in the middle does not need to be protected.

You can also invert the use of ' and " to protect the ' or the "

```
print('The name of this ice-cream is "Sweeet\'n\'Tasty"')
```

And use of 3 ' is possible too:

```
print('''The name of this ice-cream is "Sweeet'n'Tasty"''')
```

If that still don't work, could you provide the assert test ?

**Edit:**

This seems to be the issue you are facing: http://iswwwup.com/t/d08b1b05234e/print-out-text-using-one-string-in-python.html

Comes from an ambigous test requirement / IDE behaviour.

Comment: I used your third solution, which should be the right one, but still gives me wrong text. How do I provide the test? A screenshot is enough?

Comment: Then only ' need to be protected (3rd example)

Comment: Try to add another comment instead of editing only your first one please.
You can give the exact result expected.

Comment: According to the tests.py file, which is included in every exercise folder, the code should be:      print("The name of this ice-cream is \\\"Sweeet'n'Tasty\\\"")

Comment: Then the expected output should be 
 `The name of this ice-cream is \"Sweeet'n'Tasty\"`

Answer (score 2):

The last print statement uses single quotation marks, so the test wants you to only escape the single quotes that surround the 'n', so this line worked for me:

```
print('The name of this ice-cream is "Sweeet\'n\'Tasty"')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dont_worry = "Don't worry about apostrophes"
print(dont_worry)
print("The name of this ice-cream is \"Sweeet\"")
print("The name of this ice-cream is \"Sweeet'n'Tasty\"")
```

**print("The name of this ice-cream is \"Sweeet'n'Tasty\"")**

Answer (score 0):

This problem can only be resolved if double quote is used(accoording to test file)
Anyway, if you try this it will help you to finish succesfully:

`print("\'The name of this ice-cream is \"Sweeet'n'Tasty\" \'")`

Answer (score 0):

The instructions in those lessons are not clear at all and someone from jetbrains should look into this.
Even tho they don't mention it in the instructions, they also want you to edit the third line:

```
print("The name of this ice-cream is \"Sweeet\"")
```

to this:

```
print("The name of this ice-cream is \"Sweeet'n'Tasty\"")
```

No need to escape double quotes in the fourth line:

```
print('The name of this ice-cream is "Sweeet\'n\'Tasty"')
```

So the complete code should look like this

```
dont_worry = "Don't worry about apostrophes"
print(dont_worry)
print("The name of this ice-cream is \"Sweeet'n'Tasty\"")
print('The name of this ice-cream is "Sweeet\'n\'Tasty"')
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, this worked for me:
`print("The name of this ice-cream is \"Sweet'n'Tasty\"")`

I'm new to coding (any kind), and so this is just a guess - the solution requires that you print only one string, so perhaps `\"Sweet\'n\'Tasty\"` is read as multiple strings? Like I said, real beginner. (also, could be that sweet was spelled wrong?)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. 
The string is correct, but it still says I got the wrong string. Then I found that my answer is outside of the answer placeholder, just reset the task and the problem was solved.

```
print('The name of this ice-cream is "Sweet\'n\'Tasty"')
```